# Forcing zap to log every structure field

Tags: go, grpc, go-zap

I'm building logger like this

```
config := zap.NewDevelopmentConfig()

logger, err := config.Build()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Imagine I have structure Request

```
type Request {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Name    string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name`
    Surname string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=surname`
}
```

After I'm trying to log grpc request, important that request do not contains Surname field

```
logger.Infof("got request: %v", log)
```

Output message is

```
got request: name:"Bob"
```

I want to all the structure with zero value fields, like this

```
got request: name:"Bob" surname:""
```

Is in zap any config about data types otput

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `logger.Sugar()` was omitted from the example — `zap.Logger` doesn't have an `Infof` method.

`SugaredLogger.Infof` formats the objects according to `fmt.Sprintf`. You'll need to implement your own [`Stringer`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Stringer) to customize the representation. Given that the example struct is a generated protobuf, you could embed the type:

```golang
type wrapper struct {
  *pb.Request
}

func (wrapper) String() string {
  // custom logic here
}

logger.Infof("got request: %v", wrapper{request})
```

If you care about performance, you should use `zap.Logger` instead.

It's not *quite* clear from your question whether you always want to include empty string values or not. If you want them, then use `logger.Info(msg, zap.Any("request", request))`. If you don't, then implement [`zapcore.ObjectMarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap@v1.27.0/zapcore#ObjectMarshaler) instead of `fmt.Stringer`.

```golang
type wrapper struct {
  *pb.Request
}

func (w wrapper) MarshalLogObject(enc zapcore.ObjectEncoder) error {
    enc.AddString("name", w.Name)
    if w.Surname != "" {
        enc.AddString("surname", w.Surname)
    }
    return nil
}

logger.Info("got request", zap.Object("request", wrapper{request}))
logger.Info("got request (without customization)", zap.Any("request", request))
```

Comment: yep, i used `logger.Sugar()` and i need to include every empty fields, but `logger.Info(msg, zap.Any("request", request))` skips empty fields, in our case it outputs `got request: name:"Bob"`. So it's without `surname:""`

Comment: @Nikita: Do you have a code example for that? Here's mine that works as you want: https://gist.github.com/coxley/e29fe2d08b79040c9a33189159e9812d

Answer (score 0):

While logging either `%+v` or `%#v` can be used to log all the fields of the object. check this example : https://go.dev/play/p/nnemDuMh4ZM for a demo.

Comment: yes, but zap sugar logger ingorin empty fields

Comment: did u check by using `%+v` instead of just`%v` @Nikita

Comment: yep, i did, Evadore